# Handling failures when using Expect: 100-Continue with HttpClient

Tags: .net, dotnet-httpclient, http-status-code-100, http-status-code-412

I'm interested in optimizing the behavior of a client calling a REST API. In this API, a particular POST operation allows for the inclusion of a `If-None-Match: *` header, which causes the server to report an HTTP 412 response if the item being uploaded already exists in the system. When used with `Expect: 100-continue`, the server will respond with the 412 *instead* of sending a 100 response, as described in [RFC 2616 §8.2.3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.2.3). I'd like to detect this condition in the client, and avoid transmitting the body of the request in this case.

When working directly with `HttpWebRequest`, this is fairly straightforward to implement. After calling `GetRequestStream` (or `GetRequestStreamAsync`), but before writing data to the resulting `Stream`, the code simply needs to check the [`HaveResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.haveresponse.aspx) property. If the value is `true`, close the request stream and proceed to call `GetResponseAsync`.

Now I'm working on transitioning to use `HttpClient` instead of working with `HttpWebRequest` directly (for improved support across multiple platforms). Currently I'm using a `StreamContent` to represent the body of the request, and observing that the content of the stream is sent regardless of whether the server sent a 100 or 412 response. How can I perform a similar optimization to the one described above, using `HttpClient` and `HttpRequestMessage` instead of `HttpWebRequest`?

Comment: You can use a PushStreamContent style of HttpContent to control the sending of the request stream, however, I don't know of any way of getting hold of the HaveResponse property.